# Extending EnitityType - constructor arguments not passing

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have extended Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType with following class

```
namespace Main\Form\Type;

use /* ... */    

class ExtendedEntityType extends EntityType
{

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
 /* ... */
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults( [
            'invalid_message' => 'The selected entity does not exist',
        ]
    );
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return EntityType::class;
}
```

then I also registred it as a service

```
<services>
    <service id="main.type.Extended_entity" class="Main\Form\Type\ExtendedEntityType">
        <tag name="form.type_extension" extended-type="Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EntityType"/>
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

And with all that I got following error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Form\\Type\\DoctrineType::__construct() 
must implement interface Doctrine\\Common\\Persistence\\ManagerRegistry, none given, 
called in \/vagrant\/symfony3-micro\/vendor\/symfony\/symfony\/src\/Symfony\/Component\/Form\/FormRegistry.php
```

Clearly for some reason arguments are not passed into constructor of DoctrineType.

I also tried to overwrite constructor and inject EntityManager but I got that same error - none arguments passed into constructor.
Do I have to do something extra to make this works?

Working with Symfony3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing two concepts here.

You're extending `EntityType` which means you're [creating a new custom Form Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html), but you are **not** [making an extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html) for it as you're service mapping suggests.

These are two separate concepts.

You should change your service mapping tag from  `form_extension` to `form_type`.

```
<services>
    <service id="main.type.Extended_entity" class="Main\Form\Type\ExtendedEntityType">
        <tag name="form.type" />
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine"/>
    </service>
</services>
```